# Wordpress Excluding Posts from Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently very inexperienced with regards to what you can do with the loop in wordpress. Currently i'm looking to run the loop twice and in the second run through, exclude the posts already displayed. Say i have a website that has two sections that show posts from a category. The first section will show the posts 1-4, and the second section will show the posts 5-8. Is there any way to go about this? I've looked at offsetting within the loop to no avail. I'm assuming i could always make a counter to determine which loop offsets the posts, but i'm not sure how to make sure the actual loop excludes the first set of posts.

Current Code:

```
<?php $cat_query = new WP_Query('cat='.$category_id.'&posts_per_page='.$posts_num); ?>
<?php $j = 1; if ($cat_query->have_posts()) : while ($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: `WP_Query` has an `offset` parameter which you can use to skip the first 4 posts: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: _“The first section will show the posts 1-4, and the second section will show the posts 5-8”_ – that should rather be handled in the loop over the main query – no need to perform a second query, and therefor better for performance.

Comment: I know it must be bad practice, but for the sake of just getting something understandable, would it be along the lines of:                               <?php $cat_query = new WP_Query(array( 'offset' => 1 ).'cat='.$category_id.'&posts_per_page='.$posts_num); ?>